# How can I implement disabled application settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, settings

How can I implement disabled application settings ?
I saw this feature in [Nike Running](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/nike+-running/id387771637?mt=8) application.
I searched a lot about this feature, but couldn't find a possible solution.
There is no tutorial or no reference found in apple site and in the internet.
[image: Disabled application settings]

[image: Enabled application settings]

Any Ideas ? Thanks in advance guys...

Comment: are you trying to make your application look like that? with the disabled cells and control? or trying to copy a functionality?

Comment: @J2theC: I'm just researching fir how to implement such a feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. Apple has made some special settings for things included in iOS, like the `Nike +iPod` setting.

You can only use the `Settings.bundle` which is read by the settings app and then allows the user to change some settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you implemented your settings inside your App.  A `Static Cell TableViewController` is all you need.  Just keep track of the settings using `NSUserDefaults` (standard place to store these settings) and implement the `View` yourself.  I personally like settings inside the application rather than being implemented as part of the OS's settings.