# "Do Not Disturb" feature in iOS 6 How to implement?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I want  to implement the feature "DO Not Disturb" in iOS 6.

First question : Is there any framework or api apple exposed to control them through the code?

After lot of googling i found an application on the app store "Call Bliss" that provides this functionality and complete control over the calls, sms and mms.
Can anybody explain how this application works?
or
any other work around to learn and implement this feature in iOS?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the description of Call Bliss, it actually sounds quite simple in how it works.

1) Do Not Disturb must be enabled at all times. Not scheduled, not off, but on at all times.

2) It requires you to set the contacts group for exceptions to Do Not Disturb to "Bliss Exceptions".  This implies that the application requires access to your address book.

From there, it's probably wise to assume that it manages the contacts in the "Bliss Exceptions" contact group based on whatever parameters you set in the application.  It adds and removes people in that group based said parameters.

So to answer your question, no, there is no framework to do this.  The way they're doing it is likely the only way to do it currently with no public API for managing do not disturb status.

Comment: Can you please tell me about how can we manage groups in an application, like if i want to create a new group, add callers to the group, remove them etc.

Comment: See the AddressBook framework.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API to even access do-not-disturb functionality.

I think this is what the app does:

1. The app creates and manages its own contact list (called Bliss exceptions)
2. the user have to select it in the do-not-disturb preferences.
3. The App can run in the background because it uses location tracking (probably significant only to save battery life), so when the user changes locations it can update the exception list.
4. When a call is received do-not-disturb system functionality checks the Bliss exceptions list and silences all calls from contacts on the list.

Please note that reviewers complain about the lack of time based call blocking. It is impossible because the app can only execute code when the location is changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my Knowledge there is no way to implement it via code. There is no public api provided for restricting the calls.

But there is an API for detecting the calls : [**CTCallCenter**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) and a FrameWork called [**CoreTelephonyFramework**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603)

Comment: But "Call Bliss" has implemented this without jailbreaking even. I just want to know how they implement it.

Comment: @VinayJain: yes, I saw that already. Will update the answer if I get any new information. Also there are a lot of apps in which there are lot of features which can't be implemented by normal iOS, for example the disabling feature of settings in Nike's app. There is no api for doing this or no documentation. But that app have the feature. How they implemented it, only known to them :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012573/how-can-i-implement-disabled-application-settings