# Is there any private api for 'do not disturb' ios feature?

Tags: ios, objective-c, call, block

I gathered a piece of source code for blocking phone calls but I thought it would be much better if there was any private api to use the 'do not disturb' feature.
I mean, 'Call Bliss' must have been done it somehow, right?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540802/do-not-disturb-feature-in-ios-6-how-to-implement

Comment: Thanks but I already read this. I'm asking if there is any private api? 'Call Bliss' must have been done it with private api.

Comment: Bump. Anyone have a private API solution for this?