# iOS. Settings bundle. Custom Child pane

Tags: ios, ios7, settings.bundle

I have added **Settings.Bundle** to my app. I want to create several Child panes and I need to perform in them customization, like a cell in table view :(`UITableViewCellStyleValue1` or any other).

It is possible to do such thing?

In my Root.plist I have specified '**Settings Page Title**', but when my app is executed the title is not used.

The last Item(String) from '**Preference Items**' is not displayed, why it's like that?

[image: Shows difference between expected and actual values]

This is how I would like to customize Child Panes ( I mean text & position not color of background):

[image]

Is it possible to change fonts,frames of corresponding labels from code?

BTW, how to create preferences as Facebook, twitter, Flickr apps have?

Comment: Not possible. Facebook, Twitter and Flickr using private API's for doing the same

Comment: OK, but what about other points. There should be some other sorts of customization .....

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to customize the settings pane. Only apple apps that uses private API's can do that.

Comment: My Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012573/how-can-i-implement-disabled-application-settings Something similar to settings customization