# settingsBundle Textfield Placeholder does not appears in iOS

Tags: ios

I am using Setting Bundle with Textfield in my Application, I need to Keep the placeholder in the settingBundle root.plist file.

By Googling somebody says that it is not Possible.

But we have Placeholders for Facebook and twitter Applications by default.

[image: here]

Please anyone Help me to do this

regards

Comment: Private API, you can't use them. I had a similar question sometimes ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012573/how-can-i-implement-disabled-application-settings

Comment: Hey, u can't do this...

Answer (score 0):

In facebook they have their private APIs for this. You cannot use textfield in settings bundle as such.